# HTML cost calculator

Tags: html, calculator

I don't really know a whole lot about coding and I'm trying to learn as I go sort of....but what I need to do is create a simple calculator to quote a price for something. it would have one drop-down for the customer to select their option from and add that to a preset number to create a total...for example:

Amy wants to take a class....and needs to add the cost of the class plus a set tuition fee of $X. She could select her class from the drop down and it would automatically add in the tuition cost and give her a total. Is that hard to create?

Comment: No. Sounds pretty trivial. How far have you got with it? Which bit are you having trouble with?

Comment: Have you tried googling to find some code samples?

Comment: HTML can't do it without the help of JavaScript, PHP or something similar.

Comment: All i have figured out is how to create a drop down box really (i would post it but I fear it'll be really long since there are a lot of options). I've tried looking online at other calculators that people have created and they all seem way too complex for what I need it to do. I own a driving school and I need my customers to be able to estimate the cost of a class. So they would select their court cost and add it to my fee to get the total.....I had a web developer doing all of this and he disappeared so I'm stuck trying to fix my website on my own cause I can't afford to hire someone.

Comment: `Is that hard to create?` It depends of your knowledge. When your trouble starts with making a drop down box then the answer is: Yes, it's (too) hard for you. Do not get me wrong but it's too hard to start with something like this when fundamental HTML knowledge is not present. At least that's my opinion ...

Comment: Maybe you are trying to run before you walk? How about some basics in JS and HTML to get you going?

Comment: All with good time my friends, just no time for formal learning at the moment and I was thrown a curve ball recently and I'm flying by the seat of my pants here. I think I've done rather well on the website considering what it looked like when dude took off. At least now it functions. I even learned how to create my own submission form :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to agree with fabian barney about needing to increase your basic understanding there are many sites out there that can help you do this such as [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)

But to get you on the right lines you want to be creating something like this.

```
<select id="classSelect" onchange="aFunction()">
    <option value="0">Choose Class</option>
    <option value="1">Class 1 Cost 1</option>
    <option value="2">Class 2 Cost 2</option>
    <option value="3">Class 3 Cost 3</option>
    <option value="4">Class 4 Cost 4</option>
    <option value="5">Class 5 Cost 5</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
function aFunction(){
    classCost = Number(document.getElementById("classSelect").value);
    fee = 5;
    if (classCost > 0){
        total = classCost + fee;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ("Select Class");
    }
}
</script>
```

A working example can be found [here..](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/kzdLxjuq/)

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put into this, but I'm not sure it's that helpful to the OP or the community.

Comment: No actually this is AMAZING for what I need....I just need to figure out how to have a dollar sign added and the word "Total Cost" to show where it gives the total. I've already been working it to fit in my costs but can't seem to figure out those couple of things. You guys are awesome and I would give you a huge hug right now if I could.